# Chain function calls using Excel-Dna

Tags: c#, excel, excel-dna

> Is it possible to chain function calls using Excel-Dna?

I am trying to call something like this from Excel Sheet:

`=CreateAccount(CreateUser("John","Doe"))`

But the inner function `CreateUser` returns `ExcelErrorValue`.

> Demo C# code looks like this:

```
namespace ExcelDnaDemo
{
    using ExcelDna.Integration;

    public static class MyFunctions
    {
        [ExcelFunction(Description = "C-U")]
        public static object CreateUser(string firstName, string lastName)
        {
            return new User(firstName, lastName);
        }

        [ExcelFunction(Description = "C-A")]
        public static string CreateAccount(
            [ExcelArgument(
                Name = "Usr",
                Description = "User test", AllowReference = true)]
            object user)
        {
            var a = new Account(user);
            return $"{a.User.FirstName} {a.User.LastName} {a.Id}";
        }
    }

    public class User
    {
        public User(string firstName, string lastName)
        {
            FirstName = firstName;
            LastName = lastName;
        }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }

    public class Account
    {
        public object User { get; private set; }
        public Guid Id { get; private set; }
        public Account(object user)
        {
            User = user;
            Id = Guid.NewGuid();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ExcelFunction can't return class, nó phải là kiểu dữ liệu string, number or array. so CreateUser 'll not work, also can't call Class User parameter for CreateAccount as function in worksheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might add the new user to an internal `Dictionary<string, User>` and return some kind of key, e.g. "User:1" from the `CreateUser` function. Then in `CreateAccount` you take in the string key, and check if it is present in the dictionary to retrieve the cached `User` object.

Comment: Yes, that approach is know to me. What I wanted is not have to do it that way :). But OK, if to use caching of previous calls is _the only solution_, than I will accept your answer.

Comment: The data returned from `CreateUser` _must_ be one of the types understood by Excel. There are other ways to glue them together, e.g. you could return an serialized version of your object (e.g. as a JSON string) or you could return an object[,] array with various parts of your object. Probably other ways too.

Comment: Thanks for additional ideas how to overcome the problem. To use cache is the simplest way.

Comment: No need to cache anything, give the user a Guid just as you have with the account, then have CrerateUser() return the Guid of the newly created user which CreateAccount() can use.